# MATLAB Complex conjugate transpose of multidimensional array without for loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array A such that e.g.
`A(:,:,1)` is a 3 by 3 complex matrix and `A(:,:,2)` is another 3 by 3 complex matrix.

How can I get another multidimensional array B such that 
`B(:,:,1)` is complex conjugate transpose of `A(:,:,1)` and
`B(:,:,2)` is complex conjugate transpose of `A(:,:,2)`

without for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permute the first two dimensions and apply complex conjugate:

```
B = conj(permute(A, [2 1 3]));
```